# Faster alternatives to BC847C / BC859C

Tags: transistors

I wonder, are there faster jelly-bean alternatives to BC847/859 (i.e. low-voltage, low-power, SOT23, high-speed transistors)?

BC847/859 are rated for 100Mhz, something at 250-500 (and even 1000) would be great :-)

When I go to catalogues, they have RF section where everything is too fast(9Ghz+) & too expensive :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Infineon:
[SMBT2222A](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/smbt2222a_mmbt2222a.pdf?folderId=db3a30431441fb5d011445fab851018e&fileId=db3a30431441fb5d011445fbaff0018f): \$f_T\$ > 300MHz, complementary: SMBT2907A
[SMBT3904](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/smbt3904series_mmbt3904.pdf?folderId=db3a30431441fb5d011445fab851018e&fileId=db3a30431441fb5d0114460005c10191): \$f_T\$ > 300MHz, dual NPN, low power, complementary: SMBT3906

From NXP:
[BF570](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BF570.pdf): \$f_T\$ > 490MHz
[BF840](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BF840.pdf): \$f_T\$ typical 380 MHz
[BFS20](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BFS20.pdf): \$f_T\$ > 275, typical 450 MHz

Answer (score 2):

The BC847/859 are not rated for 100 MHz operation, that is the transition frequency at which they deliver unity gain. Devices are usually used at 1/10 of ft.

You won't find anything as cheap, the BC847/859 are intended for audio and similar low-frequency applications. If you can find them, the On Semi BF959 is probably the nearest equivalent for high-frequency designs. I got 500 of them very cheap on Ebay. :) The 2N5179 is still made, and I've also used that, but it's quite expensive.

Someone gave me a SPICE model for the BF959, which is useful (On Semi didn't have one). One is readily available for the 2N5179.

Comment: BTW, should I expect beans of the same transistor with higher hfe to be able to work on higher frequency? I.e. bean C with 820 hfe VS bean A with 150 hfe.. ?

Comment: It is usual to design the circuit so that variations in hfe don't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Good and inexpensive standard parts that have advantages for fast switching applications are the 2N3904/2N3906 complementary transistors. Also available as SMDs (PMBT3904/PMBT3906 are SOT23). The data sheets mention a transition frequency of 250 or 300 MHz:

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PMBT3904.pdf

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PMBT3906.pdf

For switching ("digital") applications, transistors like these are favorable over small-signal RF BJTs, because they tend to offer both speed and some (peak) current. If you look at the peak collector current specification, you'll see that some RF types have a peak collector current in the range of 25...100 mA while the 3904/3906 types have a rating of 200 mA. The 2N2222/2N2907 or SMBT/MMBT2222/2907 types are even rated at 600 mA. If you need a lot of current, the FMMT491/591 might be a reasonable choice, but these aren't exactly everyday cheapo types.